# best CRUD library for codeignitier?

Tags: codeigniter, crud

Using codeigniter 2. Don't want to reinvent the wheel. Have tried Grocery_CRUD and found it takes as long, or longer, to learn it that it did to learn codeigniter.

Looking for crud library that makes sense, easy to learn so I don't reinvent the wheel.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://www.grocerycrud.com
It's easy to use with codeigniter.

Sample use

```
$this->grocery_crud->set_table('customers');
$this->grocery_crud->columns('customerName','phone','addressLine1','creditLimit');

$this->grocery_crud->render();
```

Also you can take look at https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model
This is very basic base model class for CI

Answer (score 0):

Subjective but take a look at https://github.com/keevitaja/simple-crud-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try MY_Model to do all the CRUD functionality?
[MY_Model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model)

Answer (score -1):

Just want to inform all you that I have released CRUDDER. This is a plug-in module for your application that works as a CRUD solution, ideal for systems back-ends.

CRUDDER is developed using CodeIgniter and Bootstrap for look&feel. You can develop your own skin appart from the Bootstrapped one. Full localization is possible. CRUDDER is designed to be intuitive and easy to use. The interfaces always show on-line help tips related to the CRUDDER itself and also to your database characteristics.

I'm attaching here an image of the CRUDDER example contained in the product web page so you can figure how easy it's to use.

[image: four CRUDDER screenshots shown here]

On the other hand, you will find that configuration is very easy. There is no need to write code other than your own custom validation rules (more powerful than the CodeIgniter ones). There are only two classes: one contains all the functionality code and the other, Crudderconfig, encapsulates the configuration and localization parameters.

In contrast to other commonly used open-source CRUD solutions available, in CRUDDER all the table-and-field-specific metadata don't require to write code. All of this is contained in two "metatables", that can also be managed using the CRUDDER itself... so you use the CRUDDER to create your own CRUD rules (don't need to use phpMyAdmin, for example). This is a plus for users seeking for simplicity.

A full list of features is available:

[Open the project web page](http://librerias.logicas.org/crudder/)

Among them:

- Pluggable to applications not developed with CodeIgniter.
- Sort, filter and pagination features, among others.
- Soft deletes with unique-index collision avoidance.
- Automatic menu-type form fields based on other tables content.
- Extensible event triggering when a value is changed in a form.
- Interface help tips for fields are contained in the database.
- Designed with strong security in mind.

Take a look! Write me if you like it, have questions or want another functionality.

CRUDDER is released under the GNU LGPL license.